# ASP.NET Core - Multiple instances of Logger

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core

I am right now working with Logging using ASP.NET Core `LoggerFactory` ([Serilog](https://serilog.net/) extension). I want to put logs in controller and business service methods. I have done that via constructor injection of `ILogger` like this

In controller:

```
ILogger<HomeController> _logger
```

In Service:

```
ILogger<ServiceName> _logger
```

I believe this will be instantiated at each request, so for each HTTP request, it will create multiple instances of `Logger`. Say for each controller and each service class but it is bit different than previous methods of logging where we used to create only one logger instance and use that for logging stuff everywhere.

Any downside for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is totally fine. Typically, it's cheap to instantiate a logger, so it's totally OK to do it like that performance-wise.

Still, consider either (1) using the global log instance which Serilog has or (2) using static field initialized in a field declaration. Again, not for the performance reasons, but rather to avoid polluting your constructor with not-so-relevant stuff.

**UPD** Update on implementing (1)

Basically, it's just a matter of deciding where would you put the logger init code into. In a ASP.NET Core it would be the first line of `Main` method (that `Log` is a static class from `Serilog` namespace):

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.LiterateConsole(LogEventLevel.Debug, LogTemplate)
                                              .WriteTo.File(@"C:\logs\elbakogdabot.log", LogEventLevel.Debug, LogTemplate)
                                              .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                                              .CreateLogger();
```

(just to be clear: I took the code from a real project of mine, but the actual configuration of your logger could be different).

Then I would use it anywhere like this:

```
Log.Warning($"got a message for an unknown user: userid=[{userId}]");
```

This line could be thrown into any class and you don't have to do any extra initialization for that class.

**UPD** Update on implementing (2)

I guess in a typical enterprise app it would be inconvenient to have always remember to put the class name in the message every time you logging something. So I would go with `static readonly` field most of the time. With Serilog you can do it like that:

```
public class XYZService
{
  private static readonly Serilog.ILogger log = Log.ForContext<XYZService>();
...
```

This way you both won't pollute the constructor, and will get the class name in all of your log messages automatically. I used to have this line in a ReSharper snippet, so I had to just type `lg<TAB>` in every new class.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. any good reference article for option 1?

Comment: Sounds good. I tried to implement that in my code. and it works !

Comment: Only two things : 1) I have to install serilog nuget package in my business library to get access of Log object  2) I am not getting sourcecontext in my output template format as it is global. so we have to write class n method details in log message. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: (1) yes you have to, but it's not a big deal typically. It won't make your "business library" less clean or something. If you must avoid this, I guess you can implement your own wrapper around it, but you will still need to reference the assembly it's located in (2) yes you will have to put it yourself; AFAIK even if you're using the constructor injection approach you still have to put the method name in log message manually, it's only the class name which is written automatically; correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: you're welcome; also, updated the answer with the example of (2) for the sake of completeness

Comment: Just thinking on point 2 implementation, That have to be written in each class/controller and static instance will be created/initialized for each class, right?

Comment: yes, a single instance for each class you put it in; it's no different from any other static field